# AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, android-viewmodel

Although it is the same exception, my situation is different from [SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58775611/5777189) as I am using Nav-graph Scoped ViewModels,

Exception occurs when using `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory` with navGraphViewModels.
From startFragment, go to FirstPageFragment, `navigateUp()` back to startFragment, then visit FirstPageFragment again  ->crash

```kotlin
class FirstPageFragment: Fragment() {

    private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_mission){
        MyViewModel.Factory(requireActivity(), "hello world1")
    }
    ...
```

My Factory

```kotlin
class MyViewModel(application: Application,
                  savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
                  val someString: String) : AndroidViewModel(application){

    class Factory(val activity: Activity, val someString: String):
        AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(activity as SavedStateRegistryOwner, null) {

        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(
            key: String,
            modelClass: Class<T>,
            handle: SavedStateHandle
        ): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return MyViewModel(activity.application, handle, someString) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable to construct viewmodel")
        }
    }

...
}
```

This is my navGraph, ViewModel is for firstPageFragment and SecondPageFragment

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nav_main_activity"
    app:startDestination="@id/startFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/startFragment"
        android:name="com.example.savestatehandledemo.StartFragment"
        android:label="FirstPageFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_startFragment_to_nav_mission"
            app:destination="@id/nav_mission" />
    </fragment>

    <navigation android:id="@+id/nav_mission"
        app:startDestination="@id/firstPageFragment">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/firstPageFragment"
            android:name="com.example.savestatehandledemo.FirstPageFragment"
            android:label="FirstPageFragment" >
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/secondPageFragment"
            android:name="com.example.savestatehandledemo.SecondPageFragment"
            android:label="SecondPageFragment" >
        </fragment>
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

I created a minimal example to reproduce the problem. https://github.com/yatw/saveStateHandleDemo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/savestatehandledemo
This exception occur only when going into a navigation graph.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so I found the cause to this exception, I am passing in the activity as SavedStateRegistryOwner in `AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory`.
When visiting the navGraph the second time, I am passing in the same activity and the internal class `SavedStateHandleController`, `SavedStateRegistry` somehow saved the state already.
**(Whoever wrote this part please explain and write into the doc)**

So pass in the navGraph `getBackStackEntry`
Updated viewModel factory

```kotlin
class MyViewModel(application: Application,
                  savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
                  val someString: String) : AndroidViewModel(application){

    class Factory(val application: Application,
                  val savedStateRegistryOwner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
                  val someString: String):
        AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(
            savedStateRegistryOwner,
            null) {

        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(
            key: String,
            modelClass: Class<T>,
            handle: SavedStateHandle
        ): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return MyViewModel(application, handle, someString) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable to construct viewmodel")
        }
    }
```

Use it in fragment

```kotlin
class FirstPageFragment: Fragment() {

    private val myViewModel: MyViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_mission){
        MyViewModel.Factory(requireActivity().application,
            findNavController().getBackStackEntry(R.id.nav_mission),
            "hello world1")
    }
```

Special thanks to EpicPandaForce, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61649394/5777189

Answer (score 2):

When you use kotlin *compose* with *compose navigation* and want to use the AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory, you have to pass, like mentioned in the accepted solution above, the navBackStackEntry. In *compose* this is given in the specific *composable() { navBackStackEntry -> }*

Example of Factory:

```
class SavedStateViewModelFactory(
private val repository: LocationRepository,
defaultArgs: Bundle? = null,
savedStateRegistryOwner: SavedStateRegistryOwner) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(
savedStateRegistryOwner,
defaultArgs) {
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(
    key: String,
    modelClass: Class<T>,
    handle: SavedStateHandle
): T {
    return when {
        modelClass.isAssignableFrom(LocationViewModel::class.java) -> {
            LocationViewModel(repository, handle) as T
        }
        modelClass.isAssignableFrom(LocationsViewModel::class.java) -> {
            LocationsViewModel(repository, handle) as T
        }
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("wrong ViewModel")
    }

}}
```

Example in setContent():

```
Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = Screens.LocationsScreen.route,
                    ) {
                    composable(
                        route = Screens.LocationsScreen.route
                    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
                        LocationsScreen(
                            navController,
                            viewModel(
                                modelClass = LocationsViewModel::class.java,
                                factory = SavedStateViewModelFactory(
                                    repository = LocationRepositoryImpl(
                                        BarCounterDatabase.getINSTANCE(application).locationDao
                                    ),
                                    savedStateRegistryOwner = navBackStackEntry
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    composable(
                        route = Screens.LocationScreen.route+"{id}",
                        arguments = listOf(
                            navArgument(
                                name = "id"
                            ) {
                                type = NavType.LongType
                            }
                        )
                    ) { navBackStackEntry ->
                        var defaultArgs: Bundle? = null
                        navBackStackEntry ->.arguments?.getLong("id")?.let { id ->
                            defaultArgs = Bundle()
                            defaultArgs?.putLong("id", id)
                        }
                        LocationScreen(
                            navController = navController,
                            viewModel(
                                modelClass = LocationViewModel::class.java,
                                factory = SavedStateViewModelFactory(
                                    repository = LocationRepositoryImpl(
                                        BarCounterDatabase.getINSTANCE(application).locationDao
                                    ),
                                    savedStateRegistryOwner = navBackStackEntry,
                                    defaultArgs = defaultArgs
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

Oh, not to forget: I figured this out only with the answer of [BabyishTank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5777189/babyishtank)

Without that answer i would still be foolish